# How to add text to the homepage in opencart?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to be able to add/edit text from the admin section that will appear on the homepage. The best solution would probably be adding a new page (Catalog > Information) but how do I add the text from that page to appear on the homepage?

Another solution would be to use the Welcome module to add text but that's not so intuitive for the store owner. He has to go to Modules > Welcome > Edit. I would like all the info page to be in one place (Catalog > Information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution at the [opencart community forums](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=49922):

[Fido-X Homepage Module](http://www.fido-x.net/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=59)

Comment: The link to Fido-X is dead!

Comment: And still very dead November 2013

Comment: And stayed dead until March 2014 ;)

Comment: It's apparently been resuscitated :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are running OpenCart 2, then just install the HTML Content module under Extensions-> Modules and create a page. 
After then navigate to System -> Design -> Layouts and edit Home. There you can add an new module (the one you just created with HTML Content). 
After saving you should see your new module on the homepage.